# How to set variable to null when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In the Locals window in Visual Studio, you can change the value of a variable while debugging.

However, I can't seem to find a way to set the value to null.  When I type `null` VS just sets the value back to the original value.  I have also tried CTL + 0 which works in SSMS, but not in VS.

Comment: Is the value a member or a property? You might be trying to set the value of a read-only property, or a property with some validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Update 2023 - As noted in the comments, my original answer is not working. (I have deleted that answer).

I tested this again in VS 2022, and was above to set the value to null in the locals window.  I just typed in null, without quotes.  If the property is not nullable, you will get a dialog message from VS.

[image]